# opening a report filtered by date range not working in access 2010

Tags: report, ms-access-2010, date-range

I'm trying to open a report and constrain it to a date range. The report is built off of a saved query. The name of the date field is "dateTime". Here is the code i'm using to open it:

```
    Dim whereClause As String
    whereClause = "rec.dateTime between #" & Me.txtFromDate & "# and #" & Me.txtFromDate & "#"

    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptControlViolation", acViewPreview, , whereClause
```

If i run the statement in the query builder it works fine, but when i call the function it keeps prompting me for a value for dateTime (the popup box). I've tried brackets, ive tried the forms!myform!myobject.. i'm stumped.

Comment: rec.dateTime is the aliased name in the query. ive also tried just dateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved however, I don't know what the problem was. I went back and rewrote the SQL statement. It was pretty much the same but I used different aliases. The only thing I can think of is that there was some kind of conflict with that field name. :/